# Creating TicTacToe in javafx

Tags: javafx

I am writing a TicTacToe program that displays a tic-tac-toe board that has the following qualities:

- A cell may be X, O, or empty.
- What to display at each cell is randomly decided upon startup of program.
- Input the X's and O's as text instead of images.

In my program, I have the X's and O's as .gif files. I was wondering how the code would look when placing the X's and O's as text instead of images? Thanks in advance!

here is my code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TicTacToe extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        GridPane pane = new GridPane();
        pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                int random = (int)(Math.random() * 3);
                if (random != 2) {
                    String text = (random > 0) ? "/image/x.gif" : "/image/o.gif";
                    pane.add(new ImageView(new Image(image)), j, i);
                }
            }
        }
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 150, 150);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Tic Tac Toe");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Application.launch(args);

    }

}

    // Create a scene and place it in the stage
    Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
    primaryStage.setTitle("TicTacToe"); // Set the stage title
    primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage
    primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace "/image/x.gif" with "X" and "/image/o.gif" with "O" and instead of using an ImageView, use a Label and set the text of the label to the text variable then add it to your Pane